# Sendgrid email bulk couldn't send PHP

Tags: php, sendgrid-api-v3, bulk-email

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['send']))
    {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $body = $_POST['message'];

                $data = array(
                    "personalizations" => array(
                        array(
                            "to" => array(
                                array(
                                    "email" => $email,
                                    "name" => $name
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ) ,
                    "from" => array(
                        "email" => $sender
                    ) ,
                    "subject" => $subject,
                    "content" => array(
                        array(
                            "type" => "text/html",
                            "value" => $body
                        )
                    )
                );
    
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
    
           
    
    }
    ?>
```

I'm using Sendgrid API to send emails with PHP
I can send to one email at once but
I need to pass the `$email` variable as the bulk of emails

```
array(
         "email" => $email,
         "name" => $name
         )
```

`$email` variable set the parameter as a collection of emails
example: `$email="abc@mail.com,info@abc.com,def@gmail.com"`

How I do this?

Comment: `<?pre` shouldnt this be `<?php`? Also: are you sure `isset($_POST['send'])` evaluates to true?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If any variable should be given in another format, what keeps you from changing the format in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) `explode()` email value with `,` to convert it to array

b) Apply loop on this array and send mail.

c) Make sure to check real value instead of `$_POST['send']`

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['subject']))
    {
        $emails = explode(',',$_POST['email']);
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $body = $_POST['message'];
        
        foreach($emails as $email){

            $data = array(
                "personalizations" => array(
                    array(
                        "to" => array(
                            array(
                                "email" => $email,
                                "name" => $name
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ) ,
                "from" => array(
                    "email" => $sender
                ) ,
                "subject" => $subject,
                "content" => array(
                    array(
                        "type" => "text/html",
                        "value" => $body
                    )
                )
            );
        
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        }
           
    
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you brother you relieved my stress :)

Comment: @Gihan glad to help you. BTW Sendgrid API give facility to send multiple emails in one go rather than loop (but What I have got via research is that facility is paid). You can look to that as well

Answer (score 0):

Heyho Gi,

you can use implode() to convert an array into a string so you get your emails as array and then you could say `$email = implode(",", $emails);` and $email would be `abc@mail.com,info@abc.com,def@gmail.com`. But I'm confused why you use an extern company to dot his! You can do this locally on your machine! Don't share too much data with other companies ;)

~Tim

Comment: uVulpos I needed the opposite method of your answer, so I used explode() to convert string to array Thank you for the answer